# D3 Chained Transitions With Access to Object Data, Transition Count

Tags: d3.js

I want to visualize state changes over time, and I'm not sure how to do it using d3 transitions. Simple chained transitions are pretty straightforward. But in this case, for each transition I need access to the object's data and I also need a way to keep track of the count of the transition I'm currently on (so I know which state change to use).

It's easy to do a simple brute force version:
http://bl.ocks.org/aschneiderman/4f7a8824c96f33aa7ad48c729b739409

```
var members = [
  { id: 1, state: [1, 3, 1, 2, 3] },
  { id: 2, state: [1, 2, 2, 1, 1] },
  { id: 7, state: [2, 3, 1, 2, 3] },
  { id: 112, state: [2, 2, 2, 1, 3] },
  { id: 127, state: [3, 3, 1, 2, 1] },
  [...]
  { id: 296, state: [2, 1, 1, 2, 1] }
];

var Distance = 200;

d3.select("svg").selectAll("rect")
  .data(members)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x",0)
    .attr("y",function(d,i) { return 80 + ( 500 - ((d.state[0] % 3) * 250) ) + i*25}  )
    .attr("width",10)
    .attr("height",10)
    .style("fill", "Crimson")
    .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(600)
      .delay(0)
      .attr("x", 60 + (1 * Distance))
      .attr("y", function(d,i) { return 80 + ( 500 - ((d.state[1] % 3) * 250) ) + i*25} )
      .transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .duration(600)
        .delay(0)
        .attr("x", 60 + (2 * Distance))
        .attr("y", function(d,i) { return 80 + ( 500 - ((d.state[2] % 3) * 250) ) + i*25} )
        .transition()
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .duration(600)
          .delay(0)
          .attr("x", 60 + (3 * Distance))
          .attr("y", function(d,i) { return 80 + ( 500 - ((d.state[3] % 3) * 250) ) + i*25} ) ;
```

How do I modify the code so I can run n transitions on each rectangle, where n = the number of state changes?  Any pointers or d3 examples would be greatly appreciated.